# FileReader not working on iOS 8

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari, ios8

I can't get FileReader to work in iOS 8. The following demo illustrates this (jsFiddle link for iOS - http://jsfiddle.net/gys6rubg/1/):

```js
var file = document.getElementById('file-input');
file.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    
    if(!file) {
        alert('No file');
        return;
    }
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
         alert('FileReader not functioning');   
    }, 500);
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        alert('Base64 length - ' + event.target.result.length);
    };    
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="file-input" type="file" />
</form>
```

This console.log's the length of the Base64 string in most browsers, but on iOS 8 Safari it console.log's 'FileReader not functioning'.

Is there any way around this, or anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally edited the post while not logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[it's a bug](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/172989)

should be fixed in the next release

Comment: Nothing that's really usable. Apparently it works if you pin the webpage to the homescreen and it has <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> at the time of pinning but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I think I'll just go with a "There is an iOS 8 bug. Please use a different device or upgrade your phone" error message. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: The 8.0.2 update fixes all issues with FileReader apparently. Joy and happiness.

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem with Safari on iPhone (but the problem is not present on Chrome for iPhone!).

If you add the error event handler:

```
reader.onerror = function (e) {
    alert("error " + e.target.error.code + " \n\niPhone iOS8 Permissions Error.");
}
```

you will get error code 4.
According to [HTMLGoodies - Responding to HTML5 FileReader Events](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/responding-to-html5-filereader-events.html#fbid=l9ZUvxZTK1W)

Error Code 4 = NOT_READABLE_ERR: The file could not be read because of a change to permissions since the file was acquired - likely because the file was locked by another program.

Comment: The UIWebView is not affected, just WKWebView. Since Chrome uses UIWebView (I believe they haven't moved over to WKWebView yet) it wouldn't experience the issue.

Comment: I'm using iOS9 and I'm having this problem when reading iCloud file (i.e. dot numbers file).  It is giving me an error code 4.  No issue if the file is an image from camera roll though.